# MySQL - INNER JOIN - Global ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I implement ORDER BY clause at the end of the following query for global ordering?  That is not using ORDER BY in individual SELECT statements...

For example I would like to `ORDER BY le.learning_event_name`.

I tried adding `le.learning_event_name AS le_name,` then at the end of the query, `ORDER BY le_name ASC`, but I get unknown column 'le_name' in 'order clause.

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
           p.program_name AS name,
           NULL AS parent_global_id
    FROM program p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('program_group:', pg.program_group_pk) AS global_id,
           pg.program_group,
           CONCAT('program:', pg.program_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_group pg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('program_group:', pog.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog.program_outcome_group) AS global_id,
           pog.program_outcome_group,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog.program_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome_group pog
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog2.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog2.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po.program_outcome) AS global_id,
           po.program_outcome,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog2.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog2.program_outcome_group) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome po
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON po.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u.unit_full_name) AS global_id,
           u.unit_full_name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome) AS parent_global_id
    FROM unit u
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po2 ON po2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog3 ON po2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog3.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug.unit_group) AS global_id,
           ug.unit_group,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name) AS parent_global_id
    FROM unit_group ug
    INNER JOIN unit u2 ON u2.unit_pk = ug.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po2 ON po2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog3 ON po2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog3.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group,  ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           le.learning_event_name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = le.unit_group_fk
    INNER JOIN unit u3 ON ug2.unit_fk = u3.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u3.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po3 ON po3.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog4 ON po3.program_outcome_group_fk = pog4.program_outcome_group_pk
    JOIN learning_event_program_outcome_lookup lepol 
    ON lepol.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk 
    AND lepol.program_outcome_fk = po3.program_outcome_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group,  ',assessment:', t1.assessment) AS global_id,
           t1.assessment,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group) AS parent_global_id
    FROM assessment t1
    INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = t1.unit_group_fk
    INNER JOIN unit u3 ON ug2.unit_fk = u3.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u3.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po3 ON po3.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog4 ON po3.program_outcome_group_fk = pog4.program_outcome_group_pk
    JOIN assessment_program_outcome_lookup t5 
    ON t5.assessment_fk = t1.assessment_pk 
    AND t5.program_outcome_fk = po3.program_outcome_pk
```

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tjMA5QRi94GyqnF2SQp47T/0)

Comment: Your question might be worded incorrectly, as when you apply on `ORDER BY` to the outside of your union query, you can only sort by the _combined_ rows.  Each individual table's columns aren't really there at that point.

Comment: Not sure that I understand, but the query in the OP and the fiddle works, but instead of being able to be selective on which columns are ordered at the end of the query, it works on ALL columns with the alias name. I just want the order to work on selective columns, and order by name not index.

Comment: Are you aware that in your union query _all_ aliases will be ignored _except_ for the ones in the very first query, before the _first_ `UNION`?  Do this: _delete_ all aliases except for the very first ones, then restate your question here.

Comment: You are correct, I did not need the later 'name' aliases, question and fiddle updated...

Comment: ...but the aliases are still all over the place in subsequent queries.  Did you forgot to save your changes?

Comment: The aliases I deleted are between the CONCAT statements for the name columns

Comment: Your final resultset will have 3 columns named: global_id, name and parent_global_id, because these are the aliases of the columns in the 1st query. You can sort by any of these columns.

Comment: But I want to sort by le.learning_event and some others....If I order by name, then all the columns with name as an alias will be ordered, which is not what I want

Comment: "but I get unknown column 'le_name' in 'order clause" ... did you add the alias to every SELECT of the UNION? Only if the column exists in every SELECT will it be accessible for the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: You can see the fiddle, how should this be changed?

Comment: There is no column `learning_event_name` in your final resultset. There is a column `name` and some rows in this column contain the values of `learning_event_name` obtained from 1 from the unioned queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add one or more columns to the union to hold the values to order by. Like so:

```
    SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
            p.program_name AS name,
            NULL AS parent_global_id,

            -- add the column(s) to sort on ; first SELECT is the template with as result that all other SELECTs should also have (in this case) 4 columns
            NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
        FROM program p
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pog.program_outcome_group_pk) AS global_id,
            pog.program_outcome_group,
            CONCAT('program:', pog.program_fk) AS parent_global_id,
            
            -- add the column to sort on ; I use same alias for recognisability
            NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
        FROM program_outcome_group pog
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', po.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', po.program_outcome) AS global_id,
            po.program_outcome,
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', po.program_outcome_group_fk) AS parent_global_id,
            
            -- add the column to sort on ; I use same alias for recognisability
            NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
        FROM program_outcome po
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro.program_outcome, ',unit:', u.unit_name) AS global_id,
            u.unit_name,
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro.program_outcome) AS parent_global_id,
            
            -- add the column to sort on ; I use same alias for recognisability
            NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
        FROM unit u
        INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome pro ON pro.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name, ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
            le.learning_event_name,
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name) AS parent_global_id,
            
            -- add the column to sort on, which in this case is based on table-column ; I use same alias for recognisability
            le.learning_event_name AS column_to_sort_by 
        FROM learning_event le
        INNER JOIN unit u2 ON le.unit_fk = u2.unit_pk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome pro2 ON pro2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
        JOIN learning_event_program_outcome_lookup lepol 
        ON lepol.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk 
        AND lepol.program_outcome_fk = pro2.program_outcome_pk 
        union all
        SELECT 
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name, ',assessment:', t1.assessment) AS global_id,
            t1.assessment,
            CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name) AS parent_global_id,
            
            -- add the column to sort on ; I use same alias for recognisability
            NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
        FROM assessment t1
        INNER JOIN unit u2 ON t1.unit_fk = u2.unit_pk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome pro2 ON pro2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
        INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
        JOIN assessment_program_outcome_lookup t5 
        ON t5.assessment_fk = t1.assessment_pk 
        AND t5.program_outcome_fk = pro2.program_outcome_pk
    ORDER BY
        column_to_sort_by ASC
```

I would use the same column-names (by using aliases where necessary) in every SELECT of the UNION though, so you/others can read to what target-column you are trying to "map" the source-column.

Edit: the aliases are not automatically mapped. The order of columns in every SELECT of the UNION is still what matters. But using the same column name adds to readability.